# Style window borders of individual application on Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux, sublimetext3, linux-mint, komodo, cinnamon

**I would like to style the window border of Sublime Text 3, while keeping my system's main theme unchanged.** More precisely just changing the color of the respective window border would suffice to my purposes.

I am using *Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64 bit*.

I have been under the assumption that window borders are under the sole influence of the desktop environment itself. Yet, I learnt otherwise when I came across **Komodo IDE/ Komodo Edit** by the developer Active State.

In the image below, you can clearly see that Komodo's window border is of a  distinct blue style. The window border not only features a different color scheme than that of my system's theme, but also its controls vary in type, position and style.

How can I achieve a similar individual styling for Sublime Text or other application then?

[image]

**UPDATE:** The issue of changing Sublime's title bar is already one of discussion in the Sublime community. ([core issue 1804](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1804)). It appears Sublime does not currently support customization of its title bar. Yet, this does not rule out that a theme limited to just Sublime Text might be set via the Linux desktop environment.